# Display image at desired scale across subplot axes

Tags: image, matlab, plot, visualization

Is it possible to display an image in multiple subplot axes, such that the image appears at the desired scale?

```
subplot(3,3,[1 4 7]);
%# image scaled down to fit 1 set of axes
imshow(img);
subplot(3,3,2);
plot(relevantData);
%# And so on with 5 other plots
```

I want to have the image scaled to either a fixed size or to fit the axes available to it, rather than to the size of a single axes.

My use case is to show a video alongside plots derived from the video, such that the plots are progressively drawn in step with the video. Once the display is correct I can save each image and combine them into a video.

**Clarification**

I am asking if it is possible to produce a figure as described *without* specifying the position of every element in absolute terms.  Though one can make arbitrary figures that way (and in fact I have done so for this project), it is *very* tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

### For changing the size of the subplot:

In `help subplot` they mention that you can set parameters on the selected "axes" (that's what they call a plotting area in Matlab).

Using that, you can set the 'position', as seen in `help axes`. This property takes takes as argument:

```
[left, bottom, width, height]
```

As pointed out by @reve_etrange, one should use absolute positioning for axes 'Position'and 'OuterPosition' parameters. they can be in normalized coordinates, though.

### For changing the size of the image in the subplot:

I think there are 2 useful things for you in the `help imshow` output:

1. 'InitialMagnification': setting the magnification of the image.
2. 'Parent': determines which parent imshow will use to put the image in (never tried using imshow with subplots).

Comment: The `InitialMagnification` parameter does not change the size of the subplot image.

Comment: Ah Ok, I clearly misunderstood your question. Edited my post accordingly

Comment: If I specify the absolute position and size of the image, then don't I also have to do the same for the other plots? How do I calculate the exact size of a plotting axes?

Comment: I never tried. Maybe you can just try. Here are some more useful links: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238497 , http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/03/03/advanced-matlab-subplots/

Comment: I'm familiar with the documentation, but unfortunately displaying an image does not really work properly with `subplot`. If you tried you would find that changing the magnification has no effect in this context.

Comment: So that's why I edited my post, and added the information about scaling the axes in a subplot (as documented in the help). IMHO the -1 is unmerited.

Comment: If you add that one *must* use absolute positioning (i.e. axes `Position` and `OuterPosition` properties), but that the positions can be in "normalized" coordinates, I'll upvote and mark your answer correct.